# Will std::string end up being our compile-time string after all?

Tags: c++, constexpr, stdstring, idioms, c++20

Many developers and library authors have been struggling with compile-time strings for quite a few years now - as the standard (library) string, `std::string`, requires dynamic memory allocation, and isn't constexpr.

So we have a bunch of questions and blog posts about how to get compile-time strings right:

- [Conveniently Declaring Compile-Time Strings in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858141/conveniently-declaring-compile-time-strings-in-c?r=SearchResults&s=1|175.4358)
- [Concatenate compile-time strings in a template at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783400/concatenate-compile-time-strings-in-a-template-at-compile-time?r=SearchResults&s=2|100.5015)
- [C++ Compile-Time string manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718259/c-compile-time-string-manipulation?r=SearchResults&s=4|91.3811)
- (off-site) [Compile-time strings with constexpr](https://crazycpp.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/compile-time-strings-with-constexpr/)

We've now learned that not only is `new` available in `constexpr` code, allowing for dynamical allocation at compile-time, but, in fact, [`std::string` will become constexpr in C++20](https://herbsutter.com/2019/07/20/trip-report-summer-iso-c-standards-meeting-cologne/) (C++ standard working group meeting report by Herb Sutter).

Does that mean that for C++20-and-up code we should chuck all of those nifty compile-time string implementations and just always go with `std::string`?

If not - when would we do so, and when would we stick to what's possible today (other than backwards-compatible code of course)?

---

<sub>Note: I'm not talking about strings whose contents is part of their type, i.e. *not* talking about the equivalent of `std::integral_constant`; that's definitely not going to be `std::string`.</sub>

Comment: Have you answered your own question or am I missing something?

Comment: Do note that there's a big difference between a `constexpr` string and a string whose data is *part of its type*. The latter allows you to take a string that is not a constant expression (e.g., a parameter) and extract the data as a constant expression. This is what you see with the plethora of TMP in the string definition. `constexpr` strings have always been an option, but you simply could never take a constexpr string parameter and use its data as a template argument or similar. What has changed here is that `consteval` is also in C++20, but is not mentioned anywhere in your question.

Comment: One other consideration I'll leave: `ctre::match<"REGEX">(subject);`

Comment: "_dynamical allocation at compile-time_" - hmm, I'm not sure that's an accurate statement.

Comment: `fmt` library currently uses constexpr "strings" to perform compile-time type checking of arguments

Comment: @Marc.2377: Dynamic in the sense that the amount of memory to allocate is not known by considering solely the function in which the allocation occurs. Or if you will - dynamic in the sense of using `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 24):

It depends on what you mean by "constexpr string".

What C++20 allows you to do is to use `std::string` within a function marked `constexpr` (or `consteval`).  Such a function can create a `string`, manipulate it, and so forth just like any literal type. However, that string cannot leak out into non-`constexpr` code; that would be a non-transient allocation and is forbidden.

The thing is, all of the examples you give are attempts to use strings as *template parameters*. That's a similar-yet-different thing. You're not just talking about building a string at compile-time; you now want to use it to instantiate a template.

C++20 solves this problem by allowing user-defined types to be template parameters. But the requirements on such types are much more strict than merely being literal types. The type must have [no non-public data members and the only members are of types that follow those restrictions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter). Basically, the compiler needs to know that a byte-wise comparison of its data members represents an equivalent value. And even a `constexpr`-capable `std::string` doesn't work that way.

But `std::array<char, N>` *can* do that. And if you are in `constexpr` code, call a `constexpr` function which returns a `std::string`, and store that string in a `constexpr` value, then `string::size()` is a `constexpr` function. So you can use that to fill in the `N` for your array.

Copying the characters into a `constexpr array` (since it's a `constexpr` value, it's immutable) is a bit more involved, but it's doable.

So C++20 solves those problem, just not (directly) with `std::string`.