# C++ constexpr dynamic pointer

Tags: c++

I was reading the manual for std::string::data() on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) and noticed that in C++20 the definition of the method is going to change to:

```
constexpr CharT* data() noexcept;
```

How is that possible that the address of a dynamically allocated memory is known at compile time?

Comment: Related: [Will std::string end up being our compile-time string after all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57129245/9716597)

Comment: TL;DR: it knows the address of dynamically allocated memory at compile time when the memory is dynamically allocated *at compile time*.