# Compile Time string manipulation

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

I've read through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718259/c-compile-time-string-manipulation) to my question already but it hasn't been answered in a decade so I'm hoping things have changed.

I'm looking for a way to remove whitespace from a `const char *` at compile time. (Producing a new string) For example:

```
constexpr static const char * initial = "hello world";
constexpr static const char * after = strip_whitespace(initial);  // "helloworld"
```

But I have no idea how to implement something like `strip_whitespace` as either a constexpr function or macro.

Comment: It's not going to be easy. Here's obtaining N concatenations of a string in compile time, and it takes ungodly amounts of boilerplate to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABg4_EV5L3w

Comment: How does one even allocate persistent memory in constexpr? IIUC any memory you allocate dynamically in a constexpr function has to be deallocated before the function returns. Has this changed recently?

Comment: You can use ordinary code to implement this, but C++ currently doesn't let you keep pointers and whatnot hanging around after you're done computing it. The workaround right now is to first calculate the size and then write the result into a fixed-size type like `std::array` (which, yes, can often mean running the same computation twice). How you calculate the size and produce the `std::array` is the same code you'd write to do it at runtime (though `std::isspace` isn't `constexpr`, so maybe a bit of extra work).

Comment: Macros cannot do this.  String literals are (single) tokens.  The preprocessor can combine multiple tokens into a single one in a couple of different ways, but it has no mechanism at all for decomposing tokens.

Comment: When the work must be done at compile time and the template and macro work necessary to do it starts getting ugly, I wuss out, write a program that generates easy-to-read code that provides the ultimate goal, and build a rule in the makefile run the generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `const char*` to store pointers to compile time strings is something you should avoid.  Compile time string manipulation libraries use fixed size buffers usually.

you start with this, a basic compile time string:

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct ct_string {
  char bytes[N];

  constexpr std::size_t size() const {
    std::size_t r = 0;
    while(r + 1 < N && bytes[r])
      ++r;
    return r;
  }

  constexpr char& operator[](std::size_t i) { return bytes[i]; }
  constexpr char const& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return bytes[i]; }

  constexpr ct_string( char const(&arr)[N] ) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      bytes[i] = arr[i];
  }

  constexpr char const* data() const { return bytes; }
  constexpr operator char const*() const { return data(); }
};
```

we can then add a few operations:

```
template<std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
constexpr ct_string<A+B-1> operator+( ct_string<A> lhs, ct_string<B> rhs ) {
  ct_string<A+B-1> retval;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < lhs.size(); ++i)
    retval[i] = lhs[i];
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < B; ++i)
    retval[lhs.size()+i] = rhs[i];
  for (std::size_t i = lhs.size(); i < A; ++i)
    retval[B+i] = 0;

  return retval;
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr ct_string<N> filter( ct_string<N> lhs, char x ) {
  std::size_t j = 0;
  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  {
    lhs[j] = lhs[i];
    if (lhs[i] != x)
    {
      ++j;
    }
  }
  for(j = j+1; j < N; ++j)
    lhs[j] = 0;
  return lhs;
}
```

use is simple:

```
constexpr ct_string hello_world = "hello world";
constexpr ct_string shorten = filter(hello_world, ' ');
```

and test code:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  printf("%s\n", hello_world.data());
  printf("%s\n", shorten.data());
}
```

fancier code, like supporting stuff that isn't `' '` as whitespace, is left to you.

My buffers are always at least long enough, always null terminated, and extra nulls are appended if we shorten the string algorithmically.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/W4hEj8nzz).