How to strip a string given as a const char[] through a constexpr function?
I want to define a constexpr function strip_string which allows:

Trim the string (removal of contiguous whitespaces in the beginning and end of the string.
Normalize contiguous whitespaces in the middle of the string to one space.
Return a const char* of the final size as a constant so the binary will contain the reduced string and not the original string.
The size of the resulted string should be the reduced one, not the size of the original string.

The purpose is to keep a readable string in the source and have the shortest string in the binary.
I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2017.
As an example:
I want that in my source (and only in my source, not in my binary!):
R"SQL("

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "MyTable" (
    "ID"                    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Field1"                TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Field2"                TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("ID")
)

)SQL"

And only that in my binary (and no original string!):
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "MyTable" ( "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL, "Field1" TEXT NOT NULL, "Field2" TEXT, PRIMARY KEY("ID"))

And here the last attempt of code which still shows using constexpr before each functions is not enough to turn them into real constants:
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

constexpr bool is_whitespace(char c) {
    return c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\f' || c == '\v';
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t calculate_final_length(const char (&input)[N]) {
    std::size_t start = 0;
    std::size_t end = N - 1;

    while (start < end && is_whitespace(input[start])) {
        ++start;
    }

    while (end > start && is_whitespace(input[end - 1])) {
        --end;
    }

    std::size_t trimmed_length = end - start;

    std::size_t final_length = 0;
    bool in_whitespace = false;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < trimmed_length; ++i) {
        char c = input[start + i];
        if (is_whitespace(c)) {
            if (!in_whitespace) {
                ++final_length;
                in_whitespace = true;
            }
        } else {
            ++final_length;
            in_whitespace = false;
        }
    }

    return final_length;
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto strip_string(const char (&input)[N]) {
    constexpr std::size_t final_length = calculate_final_length(input); // Fails to turn it into constant

    char result[final_length + 1] = {};
    std::size_t out_index = 0;
    bool in_whitespace = false;

    // Calculer les indices de début et de fin après suppression des blancs
    std::size_t start = 0;
    std::size_t end = N - 1;

    while (start < end && is_whitespace(input[start])) {
        ++start;
    }

    while (end > start && is_whitespace(input[end - 1])) {
        --end;
    }

    // Calculer la longueur après trim
    std::size_t trimmed_length = end - start;

    // Remplir le tableau résultant avec les caractères traités
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < trimmed_length; ++i) {
        char c = input[start + i];
        if (is_whitespace(c)) {
            if (!in_whitespace) {
                result[out_index++] = ' ';
                in_whitespace = true;
            }
        } else {
            result[out_index++] = c;
            in_whitespace = false;
        }
    }

    result[out_index] = '\0';

    return result;
}

constexpr const char raw_string[] = ;
constexpr auto test = strip_string(
    R"(   This is     a  RAW string     test   )");


int main() {
    std::cout << test;
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}

As the code was never able to compile, I couldn't test it further.

"I did ask GPT-4o which gaves me several "solutions"..."  I bet none of those solutions will actually work.

""expression did not evaluate to a constant"...." You should post the actual code that you attempted as a [mcve]

what trouble did you encounter? Please post a [mcve] of your code

I would suggest focusing on the "how-to" aspect of the question, and clearly state the desired input/output examples, and show how you would use such a function in code.

Just use C++17 std::string_view. Using const char* is much less handy.

chatgpt cannot possibly replace a human brain used for a couple of minutes of googling and writing code. This is just a start https://godbolt.org/z/3a5nTnbdq, but apparently it is much more than what you got from the AI even when putting some effort into it

"Not contain the original string" seems to be the key requirement and at the same time a major challenge. The original string literal appears in your source, and you can never assume that the optimizer will reliably remove it.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai this was my first guess to. But he wants to remove spaces also in the middle of the string.

SO Is not a code writing service. We expect you to show some effort rather than just stating what you want

@MarekR not sure if/how it can be done. When it comes to constexpr-stuff I am just a hobbyist ;)

@hlide Do not do it. Note that SQL query can contain expressions where spaces might be important. This is micro-optimization, which is root of all evil. Memory is cheap and those spaces do not take a lot.

adjacent string literals are concatenated, perhaps you can the much much simpler https://godbolt.org/z/88bTGc8Kf if you only worry about formatting of the code

@463035818_is_not_an_ai
It seems your constexpr function was unable to compile inline since the produced code keeps it as a function which strips the original string in run-time. I also tried with last MSVC in godbolt. sigh it looks constexpr constructions are limited.
Also I know the way to concatenate adjacent string literals but that is still less readable and difficult to maintain for most of my colleagues.

"It seems your constexpr function was unable to compile inline" sorry, I dont understand what you mean

it is possible to call the function from my link in a constexpr context https://godbolt.org/z/GbMrEa81n

@463035818_is_not_an_ai, it means compiler did not compile inline the constexpr function so the result is a constexpr-ed string. The resulting binary is calling the function as if it was not constexpr-ed and stripping the original string (stored in the binary) into the reduced string (not stored in the binary) in run-time.

@hlide sorry, I cannot really follow. You have some code where the function is called at runtime? Ok, but still it is possible to make it getting called at compile time, as I showed in the last link

Ok, your last is doing half (inlining the function but not producing a constexpr-ed reduced string as I don't want the original string in the binary). Moreover, it won't work with removal of excess space the way I see how the compiler is doing the things. So I guess there is no real "elegant" solution to what I want.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai "SO Is not a code writing service. We expect you to show some effort rather than just stating what you want" is not true at all. The only effort required is to state clearly and precisely what you want. If the problem statement is clear, no further effort needs to be shown. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413152

i didnt say it would be a full solution. Its a starting point. Its much more than nothing.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai
I want the compiler to execute my constexpr strip_string and transform my original into a reduced string in compile-time (without any code in binary) so when my code refers that string, I already get it in the "optimal" size. Look at the assembly code, the string in the binary is in its original size.

@cigien that comment was from a time when OP mentioned they asked chatgpt for a solution. And that was the only evidence of their effort. I think we can ask for some research effort before asking. OP mentioned they had code that had errors, but didnt show that code. So much just for context. The question has been edited since then. Though the comments are still dealing with code that is only linked in comments. Anyhow, this answer nicely reflects my opinion I think

@463035818_is_not_an_ai
Take it easy :) I'm not criticizing you. I'm just explaining what the result I wanted (no original string in the binary). I think your attempts are showing me there is probably no solution in what I want. Anyway, thanks for your help.

no heavy taking on my side. Though comments shouldnt be used for extended discussion (about code that is only linked in comments). I still think adding some attempted solution to the question would be good, because then you could point out in the question what you want better/different.

fwiw, I did initially vote to close for missing details, because initially the question was taking about problems in code without showing the code. I no longer think thats the valid close reason, though I dont want to singlehandedly reopen either

The problem with the question in its current form is it's pretty much asking "how do I write a SQL parser so that redundant elements can be removed?", so it's way too broad.

user12002570
I didn't have a lot of expectation about AI. Sometimes it gives a good solution, sometimes it goes round in circles. I try several corrections with it but I think it keeps to give me code as if they were normal function (just preceding functions with constexpr). I think it was a dream as I believe constexpr functions can be silently turned into normal functions (checked with godbolt). So I didn't bother to post those codes as they were numereous but too unsastifying.

@Passer By
The question is not about parsing a SQL parser. SQL string was just an example where I assume table names and field names doesn't contain space.

I hope the last editions I did make the intent clear as glass.

I think there is an exact dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77802986/3966456

@WeijunZhou Thanks, I'll check it. I call it "strip_string"  but it isn't strictly identical (I dont mean to remove all the whitespaces in the middle. But that link should be a good start for experimentation.

The error means:
An expression declared as const or constexpr didn't evaluate to a constant at compile time.
Check the Compiler Error C2131 sammple:
struct test
{
    static const int array_size; // To fix, init array_size here.
    int size_array[array_size];  // C2131
};


const int test::array_size = 42;

Even the example link in the comments uses const N.
template<std::size_t N>
struct ct_string {
  char bytes[N];

char result[final_length + 1] = {};
using non-const variables does not meet the  requirements.

constexpr std::size_t final_length = calculate_final_length(input); // Fails to turn it into constant.
char result[final_length + 1] = {};
As you may notice, final_length is supposedly to be static constant constexpr-able but for an unknown reason, calculate_final_length is turned into a normal non-contexpre-ed function by the compiler despite its definition. I believe I have the same issue with gcc (tested under godbot) so there is probably something fishy about how calculate_final_length is written. As I already told about the other link, that one may be a good start.

Use template<std::size_t len> constexpr char* strip_string(const char* input,std::size_t N).
Call calculate_final_length before strip_string to get length, and then pass length to the template parameter len. N is the  size of input.
